# can't get request parameter with core taglib, works with request.getparameter?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

EDIT: found it at last. It doesn't work in Jetty for some reason, but worked in Tomcat when i built and ran there. No idea why though...

Oh, man i went crazy last night trying to sort this out...

simple premise:

using a Spring requestdispatcher and controller class, simple jsp page as view.

in my controller:

```
request.setAttribute("banana", "myValue");
```

if use the reqular jsp code:

```
<%=request.getAttribute("banana")%>
```

it prints as expected

but i CANT get it to work using c-taglib. I've tried everything:

```
<c:out value="${param.banana}"/> <c:out value="${requestScope.banana}"/> and like 4 more.
```

Nothing works... it just prints the value as-is i.e. ${param.banana} as text.

I have looked around but couldn't find any solution, i must be an idiot. Please help me out.

EDIT forgot to clarify:
i have included the appropriate jspheader

```
<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt' %>
```

also tried

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: I wonder, if I write a customer taglib, and don't pass the "${requestScope.banana}" into my_taglib, may I get the requestScope in the java class which implements the my_taglib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others reference:

This was an issue with the Jetty server i ran on. When deploying on Tomcat, everything worked as expected.

I'm not exactly sure what it was, i ran it as-is from within Intellj, but guess it had something to do with what libraries were deployed with the Jetty on start-up.

Answer (score 2):

You probably just forgot to declare the use of the core taglib at the beginning of the JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

And the appropriate way is :

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.banana}"/>
```

or just

```
<c:out value="${banana}"/>
```

unless you have a page-scope attribute with the same name.

Comment: Many thanks for taking your time! No ,i did include headers, even tried with new/old. Clarified comment. As for how to do it, as i mentioned i tried with about 4 different ways, including all you mentioned...... (the typo wasn't in the code) *cries* ;)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a minimal but complete JSP page that exhibits the problem, and the generated HTML code (as can bee seen by doing View Page Source in the browser).

Comment: i found it... it's jetty, doesn't work there but works when i build and run in Tomcat... no idea how to fix it tho.